# Auto-completion pop-up no clean up - how to debug

Tags: autocompletion, redraw, popup-menu

I'm trying to solve this issue for some time now. Quite often auto-suggestion pop-up leaves a text on the screen:

- even after being closed
- sometimes covering newer suggestion that was displayed after typing new letters.

[image]
[image]

I had this issue with `youcompleteme` plugin and now I have it as well with `CoC`. The same on Ubuntu machine as well as in WSL.
I don't really know how to deal with it. I can clean vim with `:redraw` in normal mode, but I can't use it in insert mode, and that sometimes annoying when old auto-suggestion results hover new one. These "artifacts" disappear after I hover it with a cursor.

Do you have any ideas on how I can debug it?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I wonder if using `set t_ut=` (clearing it) fixes this problem for you...? We've seen issues on the WSL terminal related to background color not being cleared on the end of the lines, I wonder if it's something similar here... Can you try it and let us know if that seems to fix it? If it does, I'd be happy to turn that into an answer. Cheers!

Comment: It's the same with `set t_ut=`. It's hard to reproduce because it's happening in different circumstances. Overall it's worse over time, I think the issue is more frequent when more files are in a buffer, and few tabs are opened. Also, I spot it more frequently with `NERDTree` opened, but removing `NERDTree` plugin doesn't fix it.

Comment: I tried on Ubuntu this weekend and it's even worse there with just a single file.

Comment: Which terminal emulator? I think this is most likely related to your terminal emulator and not to Vim itself...

Comment: On Windows, I use Hyper and on Ubuntu just plain Ubuntu terminal. I tested also on Windows `wsl.exe` and the result is pretty the same.